# restify jsonClient failing at post

Tags: json, node.js, post, restify

createJsonClient to post my data to a restify server like

```
console.log(typeof payload); // string
payload = JSON.parse(payload).Body;
console.log(payload); //object

client.post('/sqs', payload, function (err, req, res, obj) {
if (err) 
   callback(err, null);
else {
   console.log(obj);
}
});
```

But I'm getting

```
{ [InternalError: Unexpected token o]\n  message: 'Unexpected token o',\n  statusCode: 500,\n  body: { code: 'InternalError', message: 'Unexpected token o' },\n  restCode: 'InternalError',\n  name: 'InternalError' }
```

The payload is a valid JSON object after JSON.parse, How do post an object in restify.createJsonClient ?

Comment: What happens if you put in an object literal instead of payload to the client.post call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your payload is an object, while you need to send JSON string, so just remove line

```
payload = JSON.parse(payload).Body;
```

from restify docs:

```
client.post('/foo', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, req, res, obj) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('%d -> %j', res.statusCode, res.headers);
  console.log('%j', obj);
});
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: show us how your JSON looks like, maybe it's not valid

Comment: im getting AssertionError: body (object) is required